# Fetch company posts and comments with Linkedin API

Tags: api, linked-list, linkedin-api

I'm trying to fetch LinkedIn company page posts using the LinkedIn API. I created my app with permissions set up, and I verified the company. Then I used this URL for which I created an authorization token:

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https//linkedindata.cresol.in&state=foobar&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social

and using this API:

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

I got the accessToken and then used this in the Header like this:

```
Authorized : 
Bearer AQUau_EPV1RVuoclp2BXRGBXjvDDCS2fsULTeNDBD5xmRohRW3q7nbVu9FFfeeucPUYCnGub1erfCu1IUF66QJhW5JxpiTx160vZwWHjwdeykm33vOmGFr1avSRCBPDYlZS ....
```

It's working fine for this API:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

I get the proper response.

But once I used the same thing in another API, like

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=ownersowners=urn:li:organization:82091933&sortBy=1&sharesPerOwner=100
```

I get this error response:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares",
    "status": 403
}
```

How to find the Listing of all posts of my company page?

What are the right endpoints and API for this?

Answer (score 0):

- First did you grant all permission before getting the Bearer token?
- Second to get posts of an organization try this endpoint

`POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts?author={author}&isDsc=false&q=author&count=10`

> **{author} = You need the organization id, and the max count is 100**
> Don't forget to add '**X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0**' at the header

Please check this link for more details [LINKEDIN DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-09&tabs=http#find-posts-by-authors).